# How to get the right property of a nested object property in a for...in?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, nested, for-in-loop

Given the following snippet:

```js
let PARENT = {
  CHILD_1: {
    no: '1',
    page: 3,
    toString: function(){ return this.no; } },
  CHILD_2: {
    no: '2',
    page: 4,
    toString: function(){ return this.no; } },
}
console.log( JSON.stringify(PARENT, null, 1) )

for ( let c in PARENT ) {
  // c is a CHILD_n object here, right?

  console.log(c)  // why 'CHILD_n' instead of 'no' from toString()?
  console.log(c.page)  // why undefined instead of 'page'?
}
```

I don't get the expected results:

1. Why is `c` resolved to the `CHILD_n` property's name rather than the value returned by `toString()`?
2. Why is `c.page` `undefined`? 1. Isn't `c` a `CHILD_n` object with its properties available?
3. How to get the expected values?

Comment: `for ... in` loops through the *keys*, `for ... of` loops through the property *values*.

Comment: Also `Object.entries()` gives a 2-D array of `[key, value]` entries.

Comment: @Pointy So, `for...in` sees the object as an array of `key:value` pairs, right? If yes, is this transitive like `PARENT[0][0]` or `PARENT['CHILD_1']['no']` yielding `'1'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `for... in` loops though the keys; i.e. the strings `'CHILD_1'` and `'CHILD_2'` as opposed to the objects.

`for... of` iterates through the values, however, you can't directly iterate an object, as objects are not iterable.  `for (value of {}) {}` will throw an error.

Instead, you'll have to obtain the iterable list of values via e.g. `Object.values` prior to iterating using `for... of`.

Lastly, `toString` is not automatically invoked by `console.log`, so you'll have to call it explicitly.

```js
let PARENT = {
  CHILD_1: {
    no: '1',
    page: 3,
    toString: function(){ return this.no; } },
  CHILD_2: {
    no: '2',
    page: 4,
    toString: function(){ return this.no; } },
};

for ( let c of Object.values(PARENT) ) {
  console.log(c);
  console.log(c.toString());
  console.log(c.page);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your 2nd paragraph anticipates exactly what I got after the 1st comment: `TypeError: PARENT is not iterable`. It works now that you clarified this.

Comment: @GeroldBroser yea sorry about the comment and its implication; I don't use either of those `for` forms in my world so I have only "academic" quasi-knowledge :)

Comment: Re p.4: Yeah, I forgot the `String` context for `toString()` like `\`${c}\``. That's what I really use here to avoid `+` concatenation and longer typing/reading.

Comment: OK, now `.log(c)` prints the object, but `.log(\`c=${c}\`)` prints `c=1` | `c=2`, of course. How to print the object with a leading string now, apart form `.log("c=", c)`?

Comment: Don't override toString?

Comment: OK, yes, but that contradicts with my intention concerning `toString()`. So the latter is the only way to go.